# center kitty? in jsFiddle! forcing background down

Tags: background

http://jsfiddle.net/TurtleWolf/P7xKm/

[center kitty? in jsFiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975188/center-kitty-in-jsfiddle)

So I just want the background image to not be below the rest of the html. This is a follow up to what Evan has already helped me with in the second link... So the image will re-size to any window, but now it's not acting as a background image... What's the best practices in html5 in for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/P7xKm/24/

Breaking it down...

You want to add a content layer:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Hello kitty!</p>
</div>
<div id="container">
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="bg_image" />   
</div>
```

Then you want to take the 'container' element out of the document flow, so you can layer content on top:

```
.bg_image {
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You can then either take or leave the JavaScript depending on whether you want the image vertically centred or not.

Comment: Thank you, that is much more like I'm thinking. I'm sure tomorrow I'll be searching on how to set the back of my text to transparent... but I'm sure I can research that when the time comes. Thank you again!

Comment: Probably better in a separate thread, but: The easiest way to do a semi-transparent background (while keeping the text fully opaque) is still (unfortunately) to use a semi-transparent PNG (using alpha transparency) tiled as a background image. This doesn't work in IE6, but will work for modern browsers. Can export from photoshop as 24bit PNG with transparency or from fireworks as 8bit PNG with alpha transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the height of the image can change, you'll need JavaScript to recalculate the position when the window size changes.

Throw this in the JavaScript area in jsfiddle and set 'nowrap (body)':

```
$(function(){
    $('.bg_image').centerVertically();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.bg_image').centerVertically();
    });
});

$.fn.centerVertically = function() {
    $(this).css('margin-top', $(window).height()/2 - $(this).height()/2);
};
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/P7xKm/22/

Or, for outside of jsfiddle, add this before your closing <body> tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function(){
        $('.bg_image').centerVertically();
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.bg_image').centerVertically();
        });
    });

    $.fn.centerVertically = function() {
        $(this).css('margin-top', $(window).height()/2 - $(this).height()/2);
    };

</script>
```

Comment: No, your way over thinking this... I'm not concerned with the vertical variation of the image, it's a placeholder anyways. I just want the image to act as a background image, so the html will layer over the top of it.

Comment: Ahhh... Ok then, wait 2 minutes for my next answer